# Why do images pull the text down?

Tags: graphics, formatting, diagrams

Whenever I include a picture it pulls the text down. I don't want that, I wan the text to be normal and then for the image to be wherever it fits, either the current page or the next if it's too large.

The MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\compl}[1]{ \textcolor{darkblue}{\textbf{\hl{ #1 }}}}
\definecolor{seccol}{rgb}{0,0.8,0.3}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    In a fully implemented Operating System, any global variables that need to be initialized before they are used, and any library initialization code needs to be called before these libraries cna be used. In our modest project, there are only a couple of libraries, but they need to be initialized nonetheless. Also, the  section must be cleared (i.e we must write a 0 to all addresses in the section). All of this is done in the  function.
    \\
    Although very humble in it's current state, if the project is extended so that more functionality is added, this is where we would call any library initialization code, in order to ensure that everything is setup before any function in a library gets called. 
    \\~\\
    The very first thing we want to do is clear the  section. Thanks to our, we have a label to indicate exactly where this section begins and another label to indicate exactly where it ends, the script also ensures that all  sections of all files get contiguously put together in the final kernel image, so we know that, once we clear this section, all variables that need to be initialized to 0 will contain their correct values. Since the addresses form a continuous block of memory, we can

        In a fully implemented Operating System, any global variables that need to be initialized before they are used, and any library initialization code needs to be called before these libraries cna be used. In our modest project, there are only a couple of libraries, but they need to be initialized nonetheless. Also, the  section must be cleared (i.e we must write a 0 to all addresses in the section). All of this is done in the function.
        \\
        Although very humble in it's current state, if the project is extended so that more functionality is added, this is where we would call any library initialization code, in order to ensure that everything is setup before any function in a library gets called. 
        \\~\\
        The very first thing we want to do is clear the  section. Thanks to our , we have a label to indicate exactly where this section begins and another label to indicate exactly where it ends, the script also ensures that all sections of all files get contiguously put together in the final kernel image, so we know that, once we clear this section, all variables that need to be initialized to 0 will contain their correct values. Since the addresses form a continuous block of memory, we can

                The very first thing we want to do is clear the  section. Thanks to our , we have a label to indicate exactly where this section begins and another label to indicate exactly where it ends, the script also ensures that all sections of all files get contiguously put together in the final kernel image, so we know that, once we clear this section, all variables that need to be initialized to 0 will contain their correct values. Since the addresses form a continuous block of memory, we can
\centering
\includegraphics{FramebufferDiagram.png}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lN]Pf.png

Comment: Don't use `\\ ` to end lines except in `tabular`, `array` etc. Use the `\figure` environment to include your image, since you want it to float. You are telling LaTeX, it must go here. It has to break the page, but it tries to make the text fit (presumably, it is set to keep the bottoms of pages flush).

Comment: 1) **Don’t use `\\ ` (or, worse, `\\~\\ `) to end paragraphs:** leave an empty line in the source.  2) If you want a figure to float, use a `figure` environment.  3) Read a manual about LaTeX… ;-)

Comment: I don't want the figure to float I want to avoid the figure pulling down the text and re-formatting the paragraphs. My latex compiler ignores white space, if I don't explicitely tell ti to skip a line, it won't

Comment: How can we help if we cannot test, not having at least the dimensions of the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your picture into a `figure` environment to make it float:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{FramebufferDiagram.png}
\end{figure}
```

You can add an optional argument to setup the positioning. `h` for here (where it appears in the source), `t` for at the top of a page and/or `b` for at the bottom of a page (`\begin{figure}[ht]` for putting it here or, if it doesn't fit, on the top of the next page).

Note: your text only fills about half a page. And because you are using the `book` class it will still be streched out until you add more text. This is because the `book` class tries to make all pages the same height.

**Edit:**

In order to avoid stretching the page put `\raggedbottom` into the preamble.
LaTeX will then no longer try to make all pages the same height.

Btw.: Since you don't want the picture to float, may I recommend to put `\centering` and `\includegraphics` in a group (`{...}`). This way the text after the image won't get centered anymore. (I guess you don't want this.)

Comment: This results in the exact same behaviour as above even with the use of H, this is not a solution

Comment: @Makogan: see edit

Comment: @Makogan: 1) If the figure is allowed to float, the gaps between the paragraphs should disappear, even wihout `\raggedbottom`. 2) Are you using `h` or `H` in the optional argument of the `figure` environment?  3) To get some vertical space between two given paragraphs, try separating them with, _e.g._, `<blank line>\bigskip<blank line>`.

Comment: If I allow the figure to float completely freely, latex put's it at the end of my document (literally tens of pages below of where I want it)

Comment: @Makogan: Does that happen even if you say `\begin{figure}[htp] ... \end{figure}` (note the presence of the `p` specifier)?

Comment: I stopped testing since the \ragged bottom solution worked :p

Comment: @Makogan: Good luck, then!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment: `\raggedbottom` do not solve that the use of `\\~\\` instead of a **blank line (= `\par`)** to leave a blank line between paragraphs is completely wrong. You are only inserting two line breaks  *within* a paragraph. Even then, the paragraph skips are different and and there are no paragraph indentation in the fake paragraphs.

Moreover, you placed a  `\centering` before of ending the last paragraph, so not only the image is centered, but also the last  paragraph. The image is also part of the paragraph, and is acting like a huge character, so with some less height will end in the same line that "...memory,  we can".  Otherwise  pass to the next page, but leaving a "hole" of about 10 cm.  LaTeX then uses rubber spacing between true  paragraphs which stretch in order to make the text vertically justified.
This will happen even if the image is in a different  paragraph.

If you want some fixed space between paragraphs, you should use a command as:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
```

Note that this do not need `\raggedbottom` at all because now the paragraph slip is a fixed length, not a rubber length.

Nonetheless, is usually much better left a adaptable length (but the same in all the paragraphs of the page) as:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{.5em plus .1em minus .1em}
```

or simpler: use the package `parskip` in the preamble.

In this case this apparently is not a good solutión because you force to Latex to decide between one evil and  another (left about one half of the page empty, or left large space between paragraphs, even far of you wanted). The solution in this case, as Gustavo Mezzetti  well pointed, a float with `h`, `t` or `p`options because then the image is no longer part of a normal paragraphs.

It is worth mention that a float is also usually preferable because take care of left a decent space between the figure and text above and/or below (and allow numbered captions, list of figures, center vertically alone imgaes, etc.)

MWE without float:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % allow \kant[n] for dummy paragraphs
\begin{document}
\kant[2]\par\kant[1]\par\kant[2]\par\kant[1]\par

\centering
\includegraphics[height=12cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

MWE with float:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5em plus .1em minus .5em}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % allow \kant[n] for dummy paragraphs
\begin{document}
\kant[2]\par\kant[1]\par\kant[2]\par\kant[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=12cm]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note : `\par` (=blank line) is already implicit in the `\kant` macros, but I leave it in the MWEs to remark that paragraphs end with `\par` (and because extra \par are ignored, of course).